# could someone tell me if we can refer to a document with 他

Tags: vocabulary

I was wondering if we can refer to a document with 他? Or is it only for people? I hope someone knows.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

他 for a person, or more specifically, a male person

她 for a female person

牠 for an animal

它 for an inanimate object

祂 for a deity

A document is inanimate, so 它 is the appropriate pronoun to use. Having said that, it is not always necessary to translate the "it" in an English sentence. If you'd give us the context, we may be able to provide a better answer than a simple "A in Chinese equals B in English".